# Parse json data from yandex translate api using retrofit in android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, translate, yandex

I have an endpoint from yandex translate api i.e. https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate? 
key=trnsl.1.1.20170330T122259Z.ced3f5aaba1fb0cc.7b2060a11b18f42c68fbce10987c7538976f9c4d&text=hello&lang=ru

i am unable to figure out, how can i use this url in retrofit..

Comment: may be this can help you...https://github.com/vbauer/yandex-translate-api

Comment: already tried this library but i has lots of errors while compiling...

Comment: so want to try out with retrofit